# Make mutliple bars for different vectors in the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, counter

l have three vectors as follow :

```
y_test=['ApplyLipstick', 'BalanceBeam', 'Archery', 'Archery', 'BalanceBeam',
       'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BasketballDunk', 'BalanceBeam', 'ApplyLipstick',
       'BaseballPitch', 'BandMarching', 'BaseballPitch', 'Basketball',
       'BabyCrawling', 'BabyCrawling', 'BandMarching', 'BenchPress',
       'BandMarching', 'BalanceBeam', 'BasketballDunk', 'ApplyLipstick',
       'BenchPress', 'Basketball', 'Basketball', 'Basketball',
       'BabyCrawling', 'BenchPress', 'Archery', 'Basketball',
       'BabyCrawling', 'BabyCrawling', 'BalanceBeam', 'BandMarching',
       'BandMarching', 'BabyCrawling', 'ApplyLipstick', 'BasketballDunk',
       'BaseballPitch', 'BalanceBeam', 'ApplyLipstick', 'BenchPress',
       'ApplyLipstick', 'BenchPress', 'BasketballDunk', 'Basketball',
       'BaseballPitch', 'BasketballDunk', 'Archery', 'Basketball',
       'BenchPress', 'BaseballPitch', 'ApplyLipstick', 'BaseballPitch',
       'BandMarching', 'BalanceBeam', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'Archery',
       'BasketballDunk', 'Archery', 'BasketballDunk', 'Archery',
       'Basketball', 'BabyCrawling', 'BandMarching', 'BandMarching',
       'BenchPress', 'BasketballDunk', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BandMarching',
       'ApplyLipstick', 'BalanceBeam', 'BenchPress', 'BaseballPitch',
       'BabyCrawling', 'Basketball', 'ApplyLipstick', 'BalanceBeam',
       'ApplyLipstick', 'BaseballPitch', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BandMarching',
       'BandMarching', 'BalanceBeam', 'BenchPress', 'BabyCrawling',
       'Archery', 'BabyCrawling', 'BabyCrawling', 'Basketball',
       'BenchPress', 'BaseballPitch', 'BalanceBeam', 'BalanceBeam',
       'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BaseballPitch', 'ApplyEyeMakeup',
       'BaseballPitch', 'BandMarching', 'BandMarching', 'BasketballDunk']
```

and

```
y_train=['BabyCrawling', 'Archery', 'BasketballDunk', 'BabyCrawling',
       'Basketball', 'ApplyLipstick', 'BasketballDunk', 'ApplyEyeMakeup',
       'BasketballDunk', 'BabyCrawling', 'ApplyLipstick', 'ApplyEyeMakeup',
       'BaseballPitch', 'Archery', 'BalanceBeam', 'ApplyEyeMakeup',
       'ApplyLipstick', 'BalanceBeam', 'BaseballPitch', 'BaseballPitch',
       'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'Archery', 'BalanceBeam', 'BasketballDunk',
       'BalanceBeam', 'ApplyLipstick', 'Basketball', 'BandMarching',
       'BenchPress', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'ApplyLipstick', 'Archery',
       'BaseballPitch', 'BalanceBeam', 'Basketball', 'BaseballPitch',
       'BasketballDunk', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BenchPress', 'BandMarching',
       'BabyCrawling', 'BasketballDunk', 'BandMarching', 'BabyCrawling',
       'BalanceBeam', 'BasketballDunk', 'BaseballPitch', 'Basketball',
       'Archery', 'ApplyLipstick', 'ApplyLipstick', 'BasketballDunk',
       'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'Archery', 'BasketballDunk',
       'BabyCrawling', 'BenchPress', 'Basketball', 'BabyCrawling',
       'BenchPress', 'BabyCrawling', 'BenchPress', 'Basketball',
       'BenchPress', 'Archery', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'Archery', 'BenchPress',
       'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BaseballPitch', 'Archery', 'BaseballPitch',
       'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'Basketball', 'BandMarching', 'ApplyLipstick',
       'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'Basketball', 'BenchPress', 'Archery',
       'Basketball', 'ApplyLipstick', 'Basketball', 'BasketballDunk',
       'Archery', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BalanceBeam', 'BandMarching',
       'BasketballDunk', 'BandMarching', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BandMarching',
       'BabyCrawling', 'BenchPress', 'ApplyLipstick', 'BenchPress',
       'BaseballPitch', 'Archery', 'BandMarching']
```

and classes :

```
classes=['BenchPress', 'ApplyLipstick', 'BabyCrawling', 'BandMarching', 'Archery', 'Basketball', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BalanceBeam', 'BaseballPitch', 'BasketballDunk']
```

l would to get in the same plot, bars for **y_test**  and **y_train** (in two different colors). I tried the following, hovewer it works just for 1 vector. How can l extend it to make y_test and y_train in the same plot

```
    from collections import Counter
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    y_train=np.asarray(y_train)
    y_test=np.asarray(y_test)


    labels, values = zip(*Counter(y_train).items())
    labels2, values2 = zip(*Counter(y_test).items())
    print("labels ", labels)
    print("values", values)
    print('train',len(values))
    print("labels ", labels2)
    print("values", values2)
    print('train',len(values2))

    #pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (30,10)
    indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
    width = 0.5

    plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
    plt.xlabel('Classes')
    plt.ylabel('Number of example per class')
    plt.title('Training set distribution 50% ')
    plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.25, labels)
    #plt.figure(figsize=(300,300))
    plt.show()
```

Here is the result for 1 vector for instance for y_train :

```
labels  ('Basketball', 'BabyCrawling', 'BaseballPitch', 'ApplyLipstick', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BalanceBeam', 'Archery', 'BenchPress', 'BasketballDunk', 'BandMarching')
lvalues (10, 9, 9, 10, 14, 7, 12, 10, 11, 8)
train 10
labels  ('Basketball', 'BabyCrawling', 'BaseballPitch', 'ApplyLipstick', 'ApplyEyeMakeup', 'BalanceBeam', 'Archery', 'BenchPress', 'BasketballDunk', 'BandMarching')
lvalues (10, 11, 11, 10, 6, 12, 8, 10, 9, 13)
train 10
```

and the corresponding plot :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `labels` and `labels2` need to be sorted alphabetically. Also when marking the labels on the x-axis you may want to rotate the text so that they don't overlap with each other. Comparative bar plots can be made using examples from [Matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html), for example. The follwing code shows the modifications needed to your code.

```
y_train=np.asarray(y_train)
y_test=np.asarray(y_test)

c1 = Counter(y_train)
c2 = Counter(y_test)
labels, values = zip(*sorted(c1.items())) # sort the labels
labels2, values2 = zip(*sorted(c2.items())) # sort the labels
print("labels ", labels)
print("values", values)
print('train',len(values))
print("labels ", labels2)
print("values", values2)
print('train',len(values2))

indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.35 # adjust the width of the bars

plt.bar(indexes, values, width, label='y_train') #put legend labels
plt.bar(indexes + width, values2, width, label='y_test') # put legend labels
plt.xlabel('Classes')
plt.ylabel('Number of example per class')
plt.title('Training set distribution 50% ')
plt.xticks(indexes + 0.5*width, labels, rotation=70) # adjust axis label location and rotation
plt.tight_layout() # Tight layout
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Comparative bar chart.]